# jQuery isotope on first load doesn't work, How do I wait for all resources/images to be loaded?

Tags: jquery, image, caching, jquery-isotope

I've got something I've put together using jQuery isotope here.. http://jsbin.com/eziqeq/6/edit

It seems to work in general but on first load, of a new tab, the Isotope plugin is setting the height of the wrapper element to 0. If I refresh the page it does work and sets the height of the parent element based on the the items found inside.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't think why off this first load this isn't working and on subsequent reloads it is.. unless its perhaps something to do with caching the images it loads?

EDIT--

This is a caching issue in Webkit browsers as it works on Firefox and on a working tab when I clear the cache and refresh the page it won't work until refreshed again.

Answer (score 15):

You could use a plugin as suggested by `mkoryak`.

or you could use the following: (no plugin required - *jQuery only*):

```
// jQuery - Wait until images (and other resources) are loaded
$(window).load(function(){
    // All images, css style sheets and external resources are loaded!
    alert('All resources have loaded');
});
```

Using the above method, you can also be sure that all the `CSS` stylesheets are loaded as well (to make sure your page is displayed properly when `isotope` kicks in).

"[DOM ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)" fires when the DOM is ready (ie the markup).

```
$(document).ready( function(){ ... });
```

"[Window load](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)" waits for all the resources and then fires.

```
$(window).load( function(){ ... });
```

> **Note:** (by @DACrosby): load() won't always fire if the images are cached (ie, they're not presently being loaded from the site - you're using your local copy).

Comment: An issue worth noting - `load()` won't always fire if the images are cached (ie, they're not presently being loaded from the site - you're using your local copy).

Answer (score 6):

There is another option to solve this issue. You have to use another one js if your `grid-item` contain any `image`. below the js link is

```
<script src='http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.js'></script>
```

Then call this placeholder js below:

```
/*=============Code for Masonry Gallery ==============*/
    var grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
    var jQuerygrid = jQuery('.grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.element-item'
    }); 
    var iso = jQuerygrid.data('isotope');
    jQuerygrid.isotope( 'reveal', iso.items );

    imagesLoaded(grid, function(){
        iso.layout();
    });
```

You can get full and clear details from isotop's official website. [link](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded)

Answer (score 5):

Note:
1.you should call iso-top function inside windwo load event (it will wait for resources to be loaded) also you can call function in footer.

2.confirm that function call after css load.

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $('.iso').isotope({
     // options
     itemSelector: '.item',
     layoutMode: 'masonry'
    });
   });
```

also can use image preloader plugin for images loading first
http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [imagesLoaded](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#imagesloaded_plugin) plugin in chrome. Wait until all images are loaded before initializing isotope

Answer (score 1):

A much better way to fix this is to provide width and height to the isotope item and/or the images itself.
With the widnow load method you'll end up waiting a few seconds before isotope kicks in and the layout will change which is weird.

Here's what i use in a WordPress theme inside a post loop:

```
<?php
//....
if ( get_post_gallery() ) {

        $gallery        = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
        $galleryIDS     = $gallery['ids'];
        $pieces         = explode(",", $galleryIDS);

        foreach ($pieces as $key => $value ) {
            $image_medium   = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $value, 'medium');
            $image_full     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $value, 'full'); 

            $w = $image_medium[1]; //Image Width
            $h = $image_medium[2]; //Image Height

?>

        <div class="iso-item" style="width:<?php echo $w; ?>px; height:<?php echo $h; ?>px">
                <a href="<?php echo $image_full ?>"   rel="lightbox">
                    <img width="<?php echo $w; ?>" height="<?php echo $h; ?>" src="<?php echo $image_medium ?>"/>
                </a>
        </div>
<?php 
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('window').imagesLoaded(function () {

    // filter items on button click
    $('.portfolio-btn-group').on('click', 'button', function () {
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $grid.isotope({filter: filterValue});
    });

    // init Isotope
    var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        percentPosition: true,
        masonry: {
            // use element for option
            columnWidth: '.grid-item'
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick pure JavaScript example to check if all imagery has loaded before initialising the isotope library.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var imgs = document.images,
        len = imgs.length,
        counter = 0;

    [].forEach.call( imgs, function( img ) {
        if(img.complete)
          incrementCounter();
        else
          img.addEventListener( 'load', incrementCounter, false );
    } );

    function incrementCounter() {
        counter++;
        if ( counter === len ) {
            // All images loaded, go ahead.
            var $grid = $('.grid').isotope();
        }
    }
});
```