# Height issue in Chrome with jquery Isotope in responsive layout with Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

I'm using the Isotope plugin to filter my product listing. I also use Bootstrap 3 for the general layout, the page should be responsive so the column widths are percentage-based. I want equal height thumbnail images and equal width, a simple grid. First I tried with "fitRows" layout mode but I had a problem with wrong numbers of columns showing (in all browsers) and found the extra layout behaviour "Sloppy Masonry" posted by Cubica at https://github.com/cubica/isotope-sloppy-masonry - this fixed the problem with column widths when having a responsive grid. To solve equal heights I did a simple JS to set all heights to adapt to the highest item.

**My problem: In Chrome there is a problem that the thumbnail height gets wrong, much too small and contents gets cut off.** (note that the issue is there unregarded of my `resizeboxes()` function.)

The (un)funny thing is it doesn't happen every time. Also when I resize the Chrome window, the layout gets right...

I read that Isotope v2 (now beta) would handle responsive layouts better but I couldn't make it work better. Now I have tried many different tricks but I can't get it as I want. The current code works in all major browsers except Chrome... Help appreciated!

Here is my current (slightly simplified) code:

```
<div class="row" id="listing">
    <?php foreach ($products as $p): ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 list">
        <img src="<?=$p->image_file?>" class="img-responsive" />
        <h4><?=$p->title?></h4>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>   
 </div>
```

JS function to make equal heights:

```
function resizeBoxes()
{
    var h = 0;
    $('div.view').each(function() 
    {
        var b = $(this);
        if (h < b.height()) h = b.height();
    });     
    $('div.view').height(h);
}
```

And init isotope function:

```
var $container = $('#listing');
function initIsotope()
{
     $container.isotope({
          layoutMode: 'sloppyMasonry',
     });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeBoxes();  
    initIsotope();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    resizeBoxes();
    initIsotope();
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even though I read this post before, the answer could be found here: [Can't get Isotope working with Bootstrap 3 .thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558476/cant-get-isotope-working-with-bootstrap-3-thumbnail)

Problem was that when images is not loaded, and since responsive images can't have width/height values set, either Isotope nor my equal height function could correctly set the image height. So solution was simple, just setting Isotope to init on load instead:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    resizeBoxes();
    initIsotope();
    $('#listing').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 200);
});
```

I added a fadein to avoid flickering before load had finished.

Answer (score 0):

the imagesLoaded plugin should totally work (even though it has been removed from Isotope v2), I personally have solved it like this:

```
var myGrid = $('.grid');

myGrid.imagesLoaded(function(){
    myGrid.isotope();
});
```

But I also loved how this plugin solved the issue internally: http://goo.gl/sQ6yXj and it is using Isotope v2 which is very awesome